# how to setup the alerts for failed connections and logic apps automate it

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

Having failed connections alerts need to find the users and how manytimes users failed to connect to db details for weekly report

SecurityEvent

```
            | where TimeGenerated >= ago(1d)

            | where EventID == 4625
```

but this query is not giving result in log analytics workspace when running:-

where operator failed to resolve table and column named "securityEvent"

Answer (score 0):

You have to select scope beside run query button and scope to your resource. More info [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/where-operator-failed-to-resolve-table-or-column-expression/m-p/241234).